# iOS: After UIImagePicker closes, showing a follow-up modal dialog to edit image

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, photos

I have a TabBar application with a camera button on it. When the camera button is pressed, I want to present a modal UIImagePickerControl. When the user has selected/snapped a photo, I want to keep showing a modal dialog for editing the photo, adding a caption, etc.

What's the recommended approach for doing this? Showing a second modal dialog right after the UIImagePickerControl dismisses is really hacky it appears.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's hacky, but if you want, you can use the alternate method of showing a view:

```
[self.view addSubview:myOtherView];
```

Simply create the second view controller and then add it to the view hierarchy.

**Edit:**

With iOS5, the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` blocks work wonders for this kind of thing. This only works on iOS 5, but if that's your targeted market, you're golden.